# libgl error, Unity and compiz not loading on startup

Tags: unity, compiz

Recently when I restarted my dual boot Ubuntu (windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10), all I can see is just my desktop, no dash, no launcher or any topbars. Here is the output of usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p:

```
 libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
 libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
 OpenGL vendor string:   ATI Technologies Inc.
 OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series 
 OpenGL version string:  1.4 (2.1 (4.2.11995 Compatibility Profile Context))

 Not software rendered:    yes
 Not blacklisted:          yes
 GLX fbconfig:             yes
 GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
 GL npot or rect textures: yes
 GL vertex program:        yes
 GL fragment program:      yes
 GL vertex buffer object:  no
 GL framebuffer object:    yes
 GL version is 1.4+:       yes

 Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Also, when I try to start compiz manually using terminal I get following output:

```
[vj]:~$ compiz
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enabling software rendering instead (slow).
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enabling software rendering instead (slow).
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
compiz (unityshell) - Error: GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object not supported

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin initScreen failed: unityshell
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: unityshell
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
Resource id in failed request:  0x2800005
Serial number of failed request:  9454
Current serial number in output stream:  9457
```

I'll be really grateful if someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset compiz settings by `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz` and also unity by `unity --reset`, I hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't work. can you tell me what does these lines mean:
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details

Comment: I think this means that you have problem with your video driver